# Communication between two open vswitches

Tags: virtual-machine, tunneling, openvswitch

I have deployed multiple open vswitches each deployed on a virtual machine (one switch for one machine).

I would like switches to communicate among themselves.

I have gone through few posts regarding gre or vxlan tunneling. I have tried those steps but of no use. Especially when ever I try to make the ovs as "dhclient" it goes into kind of infinite loop. The command never executes.

Can anybody please share your experience on how open vswitches should communicate when deployed in virtual machines.

Thanks

Comment: Could you please add details regarding your configuration and what steps you tried? Without that, I don't see how anyone could answer your question.

Comment: @pchaigno I was following the kind of architecture (figure) mentioned in this link. https://blog.scottlowe.org/2013/05/07/using-gre-tunnels-with-open-vswitch/. As mentioned we need two switches per VM to create a GRE or VxLAN tunneling. One of the switch connects to the interface of the VM or physical machine and the second switch tunnel traffic passes through first switch and then to the machine interface. For this to happen, I have to attach the machine interface to the switch as port and make the switch as "dhclient". This was my understanding.

Comment: In that blog post, each server (called hypervisor) runs a single Open vSwitch. Each Open vSwitch has several bridges. Is that what you deployed? Could you add the configuration (`ovs-vsctl show`) of each switch to your question?

Comment: @pchaigno As per my understanding (the line drawn from interface of machine to switch in figure in blog), I was trying, as mentioned above, to add machine interface to switch as port and trying to making the switch as "dhclient". The dhclient command was never getting executed.

Comment: What do you mean by "making the switch as dhclient"?

Comment: Switch will become the default interface for all outgoing and incoming traffic

Comment: Oh, I see. Could you add the exact steps you took to your question?

Comment: I was able to do GRE tunneling using Host-only networking with vboxnet. So I didn't proceed further with the above problem.